# IBM Notes: scheduled out of office

Tags: calendar, lotus-notes

I have a user who works wednesdays to fridays and he would like to set up automatic out of office replies for mondays and tuesdays.

I have tried to set up a weekly scheduled all day event in the calendar, but I can't schedule the out of office agent to activate automatically when the user is not in the office. It's only possible to activate the agent for the first week. As soon as the first week is over, the user has to recreate the out of office reply again.

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this?